# An expected inequality involving the integral

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f:[0,2\pi]\to [0,2\pi]$, $f(0)=0$, $f(2\pi)=2\pi$ is a diffeomorphism such that $f'(0)=f'(2\pi)$ and $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{if(t)} dt=0$ and let 
$M=\max f'(x)$. Is this inequality true $$|\int_0^x \sin(f(t)) dt|\le M |\int_0^x \sin t dt|.$$
This inequality is true if for example $f(\pi)=\pi$, but I cannot judge is the inequality true in general.